# Free running /side scrolling type game in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to make free running/side scrolling type game in cocos2d.i try it in tile maps but i am

stucked due to an issue.Issue is i want to jump and after jump the player sprite detects the

lower floor boundary and get the position at floor boundary whenever don't get boundary it

dies.can anyone suggest me what i do or any tutorial etc?Or help me by code example ?

Thanks

Comment: when the player is not landing on the ground, should it suppose 'not to die' and stay floating in the air?? like in mario, player dies..!!

Comment: **i want to detect landing points and want to set the player position when it touch the floor stop landing**

Comment: i would suggest for using Box2D.

Comment: Have you check this tuto: http://www.raywenderlich.com/6929/how-to-make-a-game-like-jetpack-joyride-using-levelhelper-spritehelper-part-1?

Comment: **@samfisher can u suggest a hint means what to do in box2d or how i do?**

Comment: @yannick no...thanks for the link i will see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a basic platformer for the Global Game Jam, using Box2D and adding a couple of classes similar to the Flash engine called "Citrus Engine". You may use this as you like and take it as an example.

http://globalgamejam.org/2012/o

Answer (score 0):

I write code in my game that you want.

So i suggest that you create the player class and set gravity and velocity of player. In update method of player class set the position of the player. And add the floor in array and in update method test the collision between player and floor with CGRectIntersectsRect.

```
floor *flr = [allfloors objectAtIndex:i];
CGRectIntersectsRect([self boundingbox],[flr boundingbox])
{
  self.position = ccp(self.position.x,flr.position.y + flr.contentSize.height/2);
  velocity = 0;
}
```

and whenever you want to jump just apply the Velocity.